# Does libgdx not support jdk-9?

Tags: libgdx, java-9

I just downloaded libgdx and every time I tried to build an application it said build failed giving me the reason "A problem occured evaluating root project". But when I switched back to jdk-8 build was successful. I was just curious that if it was just something I did wrong or libgdx does not support jdk-9.I tried searching on internet but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Java 9 is still new, it takes a while for libraries and frameworks to update. If there have been deprecations in important methods, java 9 could make libgdx crash

Comment: Does libgdx have a mailing list? That might be the best place to starting as there may already be work done to get it to work the JDK 9.